# Calculate the winning strategy of a subtraction game

Tags: algorithm, game-theory

**Problem:**
Given 100 stones, two players alternate to take stones out. One can take any number from 1 to 15; however, one cannot take any number that was already taken. If in the end of the game, there is k stones left, but 1 through k have all been previously taken, one can take k stones. The one who takes the last stone wins. How can the first player always win?

**My Idea**
Use recursion (or dynamic programming). Base case 1, where player 1 has a winning strategy.
Reducing: for n stones left, if palyer 1 takes m1 stones, he has to ensure that for all options player 2 has (m2), he has a winning strategy. Thus the problem is reduced to (n - m1 - m2).

**Follow Up Question:**
If one uses DP, the potential number of tables to be filled is large (2^15), since the available options left depend on the history, which has 2^15 possibilities.
How can you optimize?

Comment: This is a so-called Nim game. Can be solved with the Sprague-Grundy theorem and nimbers. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim#The_subtraction_game_S.281.2C_2.2C_._._..2C_k.29

Comment: 2^15=32768, this seems really small so there doesn't seem any need to optimize?  (Note that knowing which numbers have been taken completely determines the state of the game, so only one number needs to be stored for each of these, namely the eventual winner)

Comment: @m69 I thought Nim game is memory-less: your options do not depend on history

Comment: You're right; I hadn't looked at all the details. Still, the same methods may be useful.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz what if it is 1000 stones and you can take up to 150?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the set of numbers remaining can be represented as R, the highest number remaining after your selection can be represented by RH and the lowest number remaining can be RL, the trick is to use your second-to-last move to raise the number to <100-RH, but >100-RH-RL. That forces your opponent to take a number that will put you in winning range.

The final range of winning, with the total number that you create with your second-to-last move, is:

```
N < 100-RH
N > 100-RH-RL
```

By observation I noted that RH can be as high as 15 and as low as 8. RL can be as low as 1 and as high as 13. From this range I evaluated the equations.

```
N < 100-[8:15]         => N < [92:85]
N > 100-[8:15]-[1:13]  => N > [92:85] - [1:13] => N > [91:72]
```

Other considerations can narrow this gap. RL, for instance, is only 13 in an edge circumstance that always results in a loss for Player A, so the true range is between 72 and 91. There is a similar issue with RH and the low end of it, so the final ranges and calculations are:

```
N < 100-[9:15]         => N < [91:85]
N > 100-[9:15]-[1:12]  => N > [91:85] - [1:12] => N > [90:73]
[90:73] < N < [91:85]
```

Before this, however, the possibilities explode. Remember, this is AFTER you choose your second-to-last number, not before. At this point they are forced to choose a number that will allow you to win.

Note that 90 is not a valid choice to win with, even though it might exist. Thus, the maximum it can be is 89. The real range of N is:

```
[88:73] < N < [90:85]
```

It is, however, possible to calculate the range of the number that you're using to put your opponent in a no-win situation. In the situation you find yourself in, the lowest number or the highest number might be the one you chose, so if RHc is the highest number you can pick and RLc is the lowest number you can pick, then

```
RHc = [9:15]
RLc = [1:12]
```

With this information, I can begin constructing a relative algorithm starting from the end of the game.

```
N*p* - RHp - RLp < Np < N*p* - RHp, where p = iteration and *p* = iteration + 1
RHp = [8+p:15]
RLp = [1:13-p]
p = -1 is your winning move
p = 0 is your opponent's helpless move
p = 1 is your set-up move
Np is the sum of that round.
```

Thus, solving the algorithm for your set-up move, p=1, you get:

```
N*p* - [9:15] - [1:12] < Np < N*p* - [9:15]
100 <= N*p* <= 114
```

I'm still working out the math for this, so expect adjustments. If you see an error, please let me know and I'll adjust appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple, brute force Python code:

```
# stoneCount:    number of stones to start the game with
# possibleMoves: which numbers of stones may be removed? (*sorted* list of integers)
# return value: signals if winning can be forced by first player; 
#               if True, the winning move is attached
def isWinningPosition(stoneCount, possibleMoves):
    if stoneCount == 0:
        return False
    if len(possibleMoves) == 0:
        raise ValueError("no moves left")
    if stoneCount in possibleMoves or stoneCount < possibleMoves[0]:
        return True,stoneCount
    for move in possibleMoves:
        if move > stoneCount:
            break
        remainingMoves = [m for m in possibleMoves if m != move]
        winning = isWinningPosition(stoneCount - move, remainingMoves)
        if winning == False:
            return True,move
    return False
```

For the given problem size this function returns in less than 20 seconds on an Intel i7:

```
>>> isWinningPosition(100, range(1,16))
False
```

(So the first play cannot force a win in this situation. Whatever move he makes, it will result in a winning position for the second player.)

Of course, there is a lot of room for run time optimization. In the above implementation many situations are reached and recomputed again and again (e.g. when the first play takes one stone and the second player takes two stones this will put the first player into the same situation as when the number of stones taken by each player are reversed). So the first (major) improvement is to memorize already computed situations. Then one could go for more efficient data structures (e.g. encoding the list of possible moves as bit pattern).